# Slow bulk read from Postgres Read replica while updating the rows we read

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, database-performance, read-write

We have on RDS a main Postgres server and a read replica.
We constantly write and update new data for the last couple of days.

Reading from the read-replica works fine when looking at older data but when trying to read from the last couple of days, where we keep updating the data on the main server, is painfully slow.

Queries that take 2-3 minutes on old data can timeout after 20 minutes when querying data from the last day or two.

Looking at the monitors like CPU I don't see any extra load on the read replica.
Is there a solution for this?

Comment: do an `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` of a slow query, preferably after turning track_io_timing on.

Comment: Aggregate (cost=249968.68..249968.69 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=325381.477..325381.477 rows=1 loops=1)
Buffers: shared hit=11974359 read=2337302 written=516
I/O Timings: read=150858.574 write=6.127
-> Index Scan using simplified_blips_new_day_idx on simplified_blips (cost=0.57..249936.28 rows=12961 width=0) (actual time=0.027..325363.554 rows=23701 loops=1)
Index Cond: (day = '2020-07-25 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)
Filter: (mmsi < 220432500)
Rows Removed by Filter: 195911
Buffers: shared hit=11974359 read=2337302 written=516
I/O Timings: read=150858.574 write=6.127

Comment: Planning Time: 3.755 ms
Execution Time: 325381.576 ms

Comment: Please edit your question to include the information.  As an unformatted comment, it is not very readable.  Be sure to preserve newlines and indentation.

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing over 65 buffers for ever 1 visible row found in the index scan (and over 500 buffers for each row which is returned by the index scan, since 90% are filtered out by the mmsi criterion).

One issue is that your index is not as well selective as it could be.  If you had the index on `(day, mmsi)` rather than just `(day)` it should be about 10 times faster.

But it also looks like you have a massive amount of bloat.

You are probably not vacuuming the table often enough.  With your described UPDATE pattern, all the vacuum needs are accumulating in the newest data, but the activity counters are evaluated based on the full table size, so autovacuum is not done often enough to suit the needs of the new data.  You could lower the scale factor for this table:

```
alter table simplified_blips set (autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor = 0.01)
```

Or if you partition the data based on "day", then the partitions for newer days will naturally get vacuumed more often because the occurrence of updates will be judged against the size of each partition, it won't get diluted out by the size of all the older inactive partitions.  Also, each vacuum run will take less work, as it won't have to scan all of the indexes of the entire table, just the indexes of the active partitions.

Comment: thanks, the bloat was the main issue.
indexing did not seem to improve the performance

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, the problem was bloat.

When you update a record in an ACID database the database creates a new version of the record with the new updated record.

After the update you end with a "dead record" (AKA dead tuple)

Once in a while the database will do autovacuum and clean the table from the dead tuples.

Usually the autovacuum should be fine but if your table is really large and updated often you should consider changing the autovacuum analysis and size to be more aggressive.